# Writing test for Ruby on Rails to test referenced field can be updated and returned back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, rails-activerecord

I am new to rails and have been recently going through a range of tutorials and want to make sure that I go down the test driven development route. I have hit a snag on how to approach writing this test.

I have two related models : `Task` and `Project`.

`Task belongs_to Project` and `Project has_many Tasks`

Inside the `project` show template I list all the associated `tasks` to that `project`.

On the task I have a status field which I want to set to archived on press of a button and then return the back to the associated project.

Would anybody be able to give me a nudge into the right direction for writing tests with associations please. It would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of testing setup do you have? Are you using RSpec or Test::Unit? As far as testing the associtation (in Test::Unit) you could do something like that:

```
#project_test.rb
def setup
  @project = Project.new(...)
end

def test_task_association
   assert_equal(@project.tasks, [])
   task = @project.task.new(...)
   assert_equal(@project.tasks, [task])
end
```

I typed this on the fly so I wouldnt bet the syntax is correct. But the gist of it should be understandable. This sort of test is the "lowest" level test, also called a "unit test" you could create to test
the associations. If you wanted to test the template you could look into "integration testing." These should be pretty helpful: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html